# Como selecionar e atribuir a quantidade

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Estou tentando usar o mysql para selecionar duas tabelas e atribuir a quantidade de linhas a um campo por exemplo

**Tenho duas tabelas**: *Grupo, Pessoa*

Quero fazer um *join* na tabela Grupo em que mostre a quantidade de pessoas atribuídas a este grupo atráves do campo **Grupo_id** em **Pessoa**.

O *Select* que fiz:

```
SELECT u.* , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uniforms where u.id) as quantidade from uniforms_group U
```

porém no retorno a quantidade de todas as linhas está sendo atribuída a todos os campos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! Faltou pouco pra vc acertar!

A consulta correta seria:

```
SELECT U.* , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uniforms u0 where u0.id = U.UserId ) as quantidade from uniforms_group U
```

Obs.: Como não pude ver todo o seu modelo relacional, entendi que a coluna que eu deveria colocar a restrição seria a **UserId**, caso não seja, vamos acertando nos comentários.

Comment: Eu imaginei que faltava isso mas tinha conseguido. A relação é entre o Id do grupo e o campo group_id da pessoa